# How can we use different Info.plist file for another Scheme

Tags: xcode

The A scheme use Info.plist file but scheme B can not.
Can I create another one for scheme B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your scheme is a specific build of your app (let's say your staging or dev app instead of the production) you can.
You will have to specify which plist file to use though.
Select your project (top left), go to your target, build settings and on packaging you can specify the info.plist file that will be use by your scheme.

Answer (score -1):

In case someone still looking for the answer,

- You can add multiple files - .plist or any other type - with the same name
- Tap on each file and uncheck the target checkbox from the right side file inspector
- Tap on project name and open the required target
- Tap on Build Phases -> Add new run script phase
- Add the following script

> PATH_TO_FILENAME_PLIST="${PROJECT_DIR}/$PROJECT_NAME/Add your Path Here/file.plist

```
cp -r ${PATH_TO_FILENAME_PLIST} "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/file.plist"
```